# How do I generate a cut-down version of an OpenAPI spec YML (ex. petsore.yaml) using the file itself?

Tags: rest, yaml, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I'd like to use the OpenAPI generator to generate a cut-down version of a OpenAPI spec .yml to build a Postman-esque web application reading these cut-down versions.

Here's an example on what I try to get. I take the standard Petstore spec as an example:

Petstore:

```
openapi: "3.0.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Swagger Petstore
  license:
    name: MIT
servers:
  - url: http://petstore.swagger.io/v1
paths:
  /pets:
    get:
      summary: List all pets
      operationId: listPets
      tags:
        - pets
      parameters:
        - name: limit
          in: query
          description: How many items to return at one time (max 100)
          required: false
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int32
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A paged array of pets
          headers:
            x-next:
              description: A link to the next page of responses
              schema:
                type: string
          content:
            application/json:    
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Pets"
        default:
          description: unexpected error
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Error"
    post:
      summary: Create a pet
      operationId: createPets
      tags:
        - pets
      responses:
        '201':
          description: Null response
        default:
          description: unexpected error
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Error"
  /pets/{petId}:
    get:
      summary: Info for a specific pet
      operationId: showPetById
      tags:
        - pets
      parameters:
        - name: petId
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The id of the pet to retrieve
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Expected response to a valid request
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Pet"
        default:
          description: unexpected error
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Error"
```

should generate a fairly similar cut-down spec file looking like this:

```
- url: /pets
      method: GET
      title: string
      body: null
      queryParameters: 
        - name: limit
          defaultValue: 1
          required: false
      pathVariables: [ ]
- url: /pets/{{petId}}
      method: GET
      title: string
      body: null
      queryParameters: [ ]
      pathVariables:
        - name: petId
          defaultValue: 1
          required: true
- url: /pets
      method: POST
      title: string
      body: "{ \"id\": \"1\", \"name\": \"Cathy\"}"
      queryParameters: [ ]
      pathVariables: [ ]
```

I never worked with mustache templates and didn't find any simple ELI5 tutorials of how to do that and if it's even possible, but I'd need that for multiple API specs as it would be too much of an effort to do and maintain it for every API manually.

How would I go about doing that? Is OpenAPI the right choice or should I go with something different?

Comment: As an alternative to tweaking codegen templates, you could use an [OpenAPI parser](https://openapi.tools/#parsers) to read the original file and generate the desired YAML structure from it.

Comment: Where would values like `title`, `defaultValue` and `body` come from? They are not in the original YAML. Apart from that, this seems to be doable with mustache.

Comment: @flyx That's kind of the problem. `title` will be a static and always string as it's the title of the API. `defaultValue` will be either  `""`,  `true`or  `1` depending on the data type. `body` can also be a default like `""` as it wouldn't be easy to get the default body generated by Swagger, as I used this one as of now. How would I go about it with mustache/OpenAPI?
  
@Helen Sorry for the late answer, but sound like a solution! Will also have a look into it.

Comment: On second thought, mustache is too limited for this kind of restructuring. I suggest using [j2cli](https://github.com/kolypto/j2cli) instead. Please do not ask for others to simply write code for you – try it yourself and show where you're stuck.

Comment: @flyx Sound like a idea, although we'd like to use something "baked" in our Spring project. (Maven Dependency) - I didn't ask for code specifically. I just didn't/don't know how to handle OpenAPI (commands) for this specific case. The code shouldn't be a problem tho.

Comment: I don't think OpenAPI tools help you here. OpenAPI knows the original structure but not the stripped-down structure, so you would need another tool to generate that anyway. This is why I suggested j2cli which takes the YAML as input without caring about structure.